# Django is unable to load angular chunks

Tags: django, angular, lazy-loading

I am trying to integrating django and angular4 but in the console I am getting

> Error: Loading chunk 1 failed.

I know what the problem is but I am unable to solve that.

This is my app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin/admin-layout.component';
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from './layouts/auth/auth-layout.component';
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AdminLayoutComponent,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  }, {
    path: 'email',
    loadChildren: './email/email.module#EmailModule'
  }, {
    path: 'components',
    loadChildren: './components/components.module#ComponentsModule'
  }]
}, {
  path: '',
  component: AuthLayoutComponent,
  children: [{
    path: 'authentication',
    loadChildren: './authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule'
  }, {
    path: 'error',
    loadChildren: './error/error.module#ErrorModule'
  }, {
    path: 'landing',
    loadChildren: './landing/landing.module#LandingModule'
  }]
}, {
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: 'error/404'
}];
```

It works without children but lazy load chunks are not loading in django.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Loading Chunks failed problem with lazy loading can be fixed by setting **deploy url**. It'll make angular to look for module files at correct location

I was facing this issue from very long time. The problem is we serve js and other assets in django from s3 bucket using static files feature in django

**Steps to serve angular project**

1. Make angular build and place it inside django static files folder
2. Move index.html to templates folder
3. Serve index.html using django and modify all static file links according to django

With this done your project starts to work. But lazy loaded module will not work at this moment

**FIX LAZY LOADING**

Lazy loaded files are loaded internally by angular, as we know the **base url is '/'** so angular will try to load files from 127.0.0.1:8000/lazy-module.ts. But no such file exists beacause its served using static files

**lets look at url for js files it'll be something like 127.0.0.1:8000/static/angular_project_build_folder/lazy-module.ts**

So we have to tell angular where to look for module files and for that we can set deploy url as below

**angular.json**

```
architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "deployUrl": "/static/angular_project_build_folder/",  
              ---- Other Configuration ----
```

**Setting Up Multiple Deployment Url**

In case your static files are coming from amazon s3 then you can set multiple deploy urls depending upon you build configuration. Below is the example for production

**angular.json**

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "deployUrl": "your amazon s3 url/static/angular_project_build_folder/",
```

Comment: what value are you using for `baseHref` - looks like you are using '/'?
And what about the `APP_BASE_HREF` DI token? Are you doing anything with it in your `app.module.ts`? E.g.:  `providers: [ { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/???' } ]`

Comment: Hi, Yes i'm using '/' for baseHref, Nothing else in the app Module, all the settings are default.

Comment: That is so strange - I just couldn't get lazy loading to work no matter what combination of baseHref and deployUrl I used. That is, unless index.html and the lazy modules were in the same folder.