# Angular - lazy loading from custom folder

Tags: django, angular, lazy-loading, base-url

I have Angular 4 application with several lazy loaded modules. I working as expected as standalone (in local development server), however when I try to deploy it using Django application...

Main page - index.html is generated by Django view from the built index.html by angular-cli, all pathing to bundle.js files are adjusted to use static content pathing and all is working until I try to lazy load...

It tries to find file 0.*****.js in a root directory, where the file is not, because is in static content location...

Changing `<base href="/static/">` would load lazy file(s) but would also change the whole url and corrupt routing... (I am also looking to static content be on external server)

How I can adjust path there files to be lazy load (0.*****.js) are located without changing `<base href="/static/">` ?

Comment: This can be fixed by setting **deploy url**. But there's a proper way to set deploy url. look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512414/django-is-unable-to-load-angular-chunks/56784323#56784323

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set --deploy-url (short-hand -d) with build command